# Single View class to handle all templates

Tags: php, templates

I just got into MVC architectures and I'm trying to create my own very simple MVC framework that I understand, with only the **core** functionality without the extras I don't need.

I made a View class, that can handle the rendering of all view templates.

My question is, should I make a View class for every view template instead of using one for multiple templates?

I did not see a reason why I would, but I thought I'd ask and be sure I'm not going against any MVC principles.

```
class View {
    private $_vars = [];

    public function __set($index, $value) {
        $this->_vars[$index] = $value;
    }

    function render($fileView) {
        $path = ABSPATH . '/view/' . $fileView . 'View.php';

        if(!file_exists($path)) {
            throw new Exception('View not found: '. $path);
        }

        foreach($this->_vars as $key => $value) {
            $$key = $value;
        }

        require $path;
}
```

Comment: You should be fine with the one to handle it.

Comment: Just FYI: PHP has an `extract()` function that does what you do in your `foreach` loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should create only one class that handles templates in your framework. You can declare it as an abstract class and then, create multiple, more specific Views (like HTMLView, JSONView and etc that extends abstract class). But generally, your approach is correct. Based on MVC structure, View class **should only locate the template file on the disk and render it**. All loops and statements should be written within that template file.

In your case, the View class shouldn't be a singleton. For every template being rendered, you should create a new instance to avoid variables in `private $_vars = [];` getting mixed up within different controllers. The better approach would be to create static method within View class and then, invoke it like this: `View::render($args)` or `View::render($args, $template_name)`.

You can do this in Symfony2-like style, so controller only returns array with variables to assign in the template (and optionally the path to .tpl, but it's good to define logic structure and force View to find it automatically). Please don't forget about returning correct response from your app, so think of headers, statuses etc.

I strongly suggest you implementing some templating engine to your app, like e.g. `Twig`. It will make your life easier and the view classes will be delivered out of the box with such an engine.

Comment: I guess I could always extend from this View class if I wanted to do anything specific.

Comment: Yes, exactly ;) That's why you can create JSONView to create jsons, or XMLView. But View class shouldn't do anything specific. It should only pass the variables to the template file, where any other logic happens.

Comment: @tereško could you please show me where I am wrong? I thought I've clearly pointed out the difference between Views and templates, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on your own wishes and requirements. I've seen many different view structures in MVC (like) frameworks. Your options include, but are not limited to:

- Using one view class per page (class Login, class EditUser).
- Wrapping even parts of the view in separate classes (class Textbox, class Form), with which you ensemble bigger views (class Login would consist of one class Form, consisting of two Textbox classes).
- Using one view class to render multiple templates. Class User would then be responsible for rendering an AddUser template, and an EditUser template, etc.

It's all dependent on the size of the application and wishes in terms of performance / resources, *programming-ease*, readability ...

Comment: In addition to point #2: I think it would be also a nice idea to implement toString() in those classes or in any other components.